# How to show spinner during mutation and refetching?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

The simplest Scenario for mutations in React Query is to call the mutation and then invalidate the query.
ReactQuery will refetch the data in the background after the mutation, after that refetch the UI will be consistent with the server state.

This is the "low hanging fruit" for mutations when using ReactQuery:

```
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from 'react-query'
 
 const queryClient = useQueryClient()
 
 // When this mutation succeeds, invalidate any queries with the `todos` or `reminders` query key
 const mutation = useMutation(addTodo, {
   onSuccess: () => {
     queryClient.invalidateQueries('todos')
   },
 })


// using the mutation
mutation.mutate({name})
```

Documented here: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/invalidations-from-mutations

Now, I would like to show a progress indicator while the mutation AND the refetch of the "todos" is running.
How can I do that?

I am looking for a specific spinner that represents the process of adding a todo from the user perspective. I know that I could somehow show "two spinners" (or a spinner based on different states), one for the mutation `isLoading` and then one for the refetch, based on the `isFetching` of the query ... but I was wondering if there is a "simpler" way?

If the adding would happen in a modal dialog and I would like to close the dialog only after the mutation AND the refetch has happened, how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onSuccess` will await if you return a Promise, and `invalidateQueries` returns a Promise, so I think (not 100% sure though) if you:

```
onSuccess: () => {
     return queryClient.invalidateQueries('todos')
},
```

the mutation will stay in loading state until the invalidation finishes.

Comment: Thanks, this works!

I was not aware that `queryClient.invalidateQueries` was returning a Promise ...